# Wordpress rewrites not working and shows 404 page

Tags: wordpress

I want to load a page with this requests:

```
/foo/bar
/foo/bar/bar
```

But this isn't working and shows 404 page:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
add_rewrite_rule('^foo\/','index.php?page_id=205533','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function wpd_foo_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^foo/([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]&param=foo',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_foo_rewrite_rule' );
```

This takes whatever comes after foo/ and sets that as pagename for the query, and then param gets the static value foo. If you need different URL patterns, you'll need extra rules for each unique pattern

Comment: is this page exists index.php?page_id=205533 ?

Comment: Yes index.php?page_id=205533 exists.

Comment: is it possible to share url? please check my answer I have updated it.

Comment: What about executing `get_query_var()` to ensure its passing? Then set the var to include a specific file/taxonomy/whatever you're trying to reach?

Answer (score 0):

The same piece of code worked.

But the settings for the Permalinks needed to be saved again.

From WordPress Administration Screens, Select Settings -> Permalinks and just click Save Changes without any changes.